# mysql_connect doesn't work with localhost on my Windows machine

Tags: mysql, windows, localhost, mysql-connect

This does not work with my PHP 5.3.3 installation on WAMP / Windows 7:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
```

After `Maximum execution time`, this error is presented:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306)
>
> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

This works:

```
mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
```

I'm wondering if it has something to do with this, from the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php):

> Whenever you specify "localhost" or "localhost:port" as server, the MySQL client library will override this and try to connect to a local socket (named pipe on Windows). If you want to use TCP/IP, use "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost". If the MySQL client library tries to connect to the wrong local socket, you should set the correct path as in your PHP configuration and leave the server field blank.

This is from my php.ini:

```
; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/mysql.default-socket
mysql.default_socket =
```

Is this a bug, or what is going on?

---

**Update**: I'm using MySQL 5.1.36 something, and I can connect to it otherwise. Forgot to mention, but this works with PHP 5.3.0 and 5.2.11. Ofcourse I can just change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, but I want to know why I can't use `localhost`.

---

**Update 2**: Adding (uncommenting) `127.0.0.1       localhost` to the hosts file made it work. But why is this necessary?

Comment: this could be a server configuration issue with the directory where the sockets are stored... why not just use the 127.0.0.1 address?

Comment: What version of mySQL are you using?

Comment: Updated the question to hopefully clarify

Comment: Just curious, what happens when you use the PDO class? (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php).  What about mysqli (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)?  If either of those are working, this well may be a bad library update.  Have you tried copying the .so/.dll from PHP 5.3.0 to 5.3.3?

Comment: Neither PDO nor mysqli worked, and copying the old dll broke `mysql_connect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filed [a bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52516) with PHP. The problem is with MySQL, and has to do with it [not correctly connecting to all possible IP addresses for a domain](http://blogs.iis.net/donraman/archive/2010/06/11/php-5-3-and-mysql-connectivity-problem.aspx).

Solution? Don't use host names to connect to databases, if it isn't absolutely necessary. This might also have a positive [impact on performance](http://www.ksingla.net/2010/06/impact-of-name-resolution-on-mysql_connect-perfomance/).

Comment: Just a heads up, the bug that you filed has been closed as "not a bug". I think it's more of a MySQL problem than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just having trouble connecting through PHP or can you not establish a connection to MySQL from the command line as well? If you cannot connect at all, verify the service is running and listening on port 3306.

You can also try to change localhost to: 127.0.0.1:3306

Or

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';

to

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';

Comment: Also an option: uncomment the `# 127.0.0.1 localhost` in: C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc ;-)

Comment: In Windows 7 ip: `127.0.0.1` doesn't exist by default. By uncommenting `# 127.0.0.1`, you make it exist. Just a small mistake by Microsoft.

Comment: Nope, not a mistake by Microsoft, but by MySQL: http://blogs.iis.net/donraman/archive/2010/06/11/php-5-3-and-mysql-connectivity-problem.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `127.0.0.1       localhost` to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`?

Comment: Amazing, that actually worked. But I shouldn't need to add it, why must I do you think?

Comment: Mark his question as answered and I'll tell you.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually a bug in the php_mysql driver.  See http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48082

Comment: I'm not connecting to `.`, but `localhost`.